# Is there any difference: "I had an accident." and "I have been in an accident."

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, present-perfect, idiomatic-language, perfect-constructions

**I had an accident.**

**I have been in an accident.**

Although the first sentence seems more common, today I have come across the second sentence and got suprised.

I checked online and saw it frequently used for cars (eg. how to understand if a car has been in an accident)

So, do both sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: If you have an accident, it happens to you, e.g. you crash a vehicle, fall over, break something, etc, but if you are in an accident, you might be indirectly involved, for example just be a passenger in a car or other vehicle, or a bystander who was injured.

Comment: "I had an accident" is also colloquial for the very specific circumstance of losing bladder control.

Answer (score 1):

both sentences have a very similar meaning but could be used in slightly different contextualization:

since you mentioned car accidents:

> I had a car accident

would rather mean that you have caused a car accident,

while

> I have been in a car accident

indicates that you suffered an accident not caused by yourself